# Meteor 1.4.2.3 adding package extracts forever (Windows)

Tags: windows, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-packages, meteor-1.4

I have a problem with adding an atmosphere package (`std:accounts-ui`) to my Meteor application.

Upon running this command:

```
> meteor add std:accounts-ui
```

It downloads successfully but gets stuck on `Extracting std:accounts-ui@1.2.100...`

Eg:

[image: ConsoleImage]

I have left it over night and it's still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been reported on GitHub and should hopefully be fixed in a future release.

The problem is that the unzip software doesn't get configured properly. This can be solved by uninstalling all unzip software and then running your Meteor application which will reinstall appropriate unzip software correctly configured.